# Tensorflow Import Error (compat.py_: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'integer'

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, import

I am trying to use tensorflow for a research project, but I am unable to import it into my program even though I successfully installed it using Anaconda. I am using a Mac 10.13.5. Whenever I try to import tensorflow, I keep receiving this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'integer' in the tensorflow file compat.py. The error is at line 129 of this file:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py

at the line: "integral_types = (_numbers.Integral, _np.integer)"

Can anyone help me resolve this so that I can use tensorflow? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I did encountered that problem also. I tried re-installing `numpy` with `pip install -U --force-reinstall numpy` and things worked. Hope it works for you too.